# Change Ownership of Account and Contact in a Report

Tags: account, custom-report-type, ownership

Can any one help me out.

I have a requirement ,where i need to change the ownership of Account and Contact in a report as per the country .The report generated is a Summary report.Do we have an option of changing them.Any help very much appreciated.

Comment: If you export details from the report, and the report includes Account.ownerId, you can do this via Excel and data Loader

Comment: @crop1645:Thanks for your response.Let me check and update you.

Comment: if using data loader - you will need to upload bot accounts and Contacts in separate uploads. Unlike the Force.com UI, where if you chnage owner of an Account it changes owner of children Contacts, in Data Loader you have to do each object type separately